# java number pattern printing issue

Tags: java

I am trying to create a pattern using java which looks something like picture below. can someone please correct tell me whats the wrong with my code?

[image]

```
package welcome;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Welcome
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("enter the rows");
int rows= sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("here is the pattern");
int i, j, k=1;

        for(i=1; i<=rows; i++)
        {
            for(j=1; j<=k; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("* " +j);
            }
            k = k + 2;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

results are something like this
here is the pattern

```
* 1
* 1* 2* 3
* 1* 2* 3* 4* 5
* 1* 2* 3* 4* 5* 6* 7
* 1* 2* 3* 4* 5* 6* 7* 8* 9
```

Comment: What have your debugging attempts shown you?

Comment: This question isn’t really a question. Try rephrasing it with what you tried and what happened when you tried it. Ask a specific question about something (e.g. Why does this for loop work less than intended?) and lastly, if you are looking for a better way to write your code that already works, you may want to visit sister site code review.

Comment: Don’t print j in your inner loop.

Comment: Your teacher probably wants you to learn recursion.  To print the pattern starting and ending with the N-row, print the numbers from 1 to N, maybe recurse to print the pattern starting and ending with the N+2 row, then print the numbers from 1 to N again.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
package welcome;    

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Welcome
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("enter the rows");
int rows= sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("here is the pattern");
int i, j, k=1;
String tmp="";

        for(i=1; i<=rows; i++)
        {
            for(j=1; j<=k; j++)
            {
                tmp = tmp + "*";
            }
            k = k + 2;
            System.out.println(tmp+ j +"\n");
            tmp = "";
        }
    }
}
```